# Get data Between Two Timestamps in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Ihave table in mysql.
In that i have two fields fromDate and todate.
I want data between fromDate and todate.
For Example i want data between '04:40 pm' AND '06:15 pm' OR '04:40 am' AND '06:15 am' OR '04:40 am' AND '06:15 pm'.

### *Table: autoresetsettings*/

### /*Column Information*/

```
FIELD     TYPE          COLLATION          NULL    KEY     DEFAULT  Extra           PRIVILEGES                       COMMENT
--------  ------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  -------
rstid     BIGINT(20)    (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)   AUTO_INCREMENT  SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES         
fromDate  VARCHAR(255)  latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES         
isActive  TINYINT(1)    (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES         
toDate    VARCHAR(255)  latin1_swedish_ci  YES             (NULL)                   SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES         
uid       BIGINT(20)    (NULL)             YES             (NULL)                   SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,REFERENCES
```

[I also attach table Data Snapshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y06Ko.png)

Comment: what query did you try?

Comment: Is it too late to change the column type to actual dates?

Comment: No.. i can chge column type.